# jQuery - SlideDown easing

Tags: jquery, jquery-easing

i was wondering if there is any way to make a slideDown() movement to look more smooth without the use of jQuery UI, just plain jquery.

I have this function:

```
function optionz(){
        $("#panel").slideDown('fast', function(){
        $("#panel").slideDown('slow');});
}
```

Well, i know that queue: false; works for animate() and i can make the animations run unqueued but don't know how to do the same with the slideDown().

The easing would require me to set another js file to load, and i really can't afford to make this just for a easing on the animation

Hope you can help me with this one.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, as of jQuery 1.4.3, you don't need to load jQuery UI to do a basic "swing" easing.

```
$("#panel").slideDown('slow', 'swing', function() {});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Comment: That is, it doesn't work without changing the formatting a little: http://jsfiddle.net/doub1ejack/hZ3CH/.  It looks like passing the parameters as an array solves the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you did wrong, wrote a MUCH simpler jsfiddle and it works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/2YtL9/1/

Comment: Figured it out: In your version you were loading TWO versions of JQuery in the same document, one from within the HTML and one from JSFiddle options. And one of them wasn't at least 1.4.3.

Comment: my bad.  need to be more careful with my cutting/pasting.  thx.